# The bug of mongoid returning first document when invoking last?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I encountered a bug of mongoid, which return first document when I invoking the method `last`

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
end

Post.create
Post.create
Post.first == Post.last #=> true
```

The versions info:

- mongoid: "5.0.2"
- mongodb: v3.2.1
- Rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 3):

That's not a bug in Mongoid, that's a bug in your expectations of the `first` and `last` methods. From the [fine version 5 manual](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/5.0.1/Mongoid%2FContextual%2FMongo%3Afirst):

> **#first ⇒ Document**
>
> > **Note:** Mongoid previously added an `_id` sort when no sort parameters were provided explicitly by the user. This caused bad performance issues and was not expected, so `#first`/`#last` will no longer guarantee order if no sorting parameters are provided. For order guarantees - a sort must be explicitly provided.
>
> Get the first document in the database for the criteria's selector.

So `first` (as of Mongoid5) gives you the first document in the query *with respect to the current order* but it no longer supplies a default order. You'll need to supply your own [`sort`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/5.0.1/Mongoid%2FContextual%2FMongo%3Asort) order in the query if you want `first` to behave like it used to.

Similarly for [`last`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/5.0.1/Mongoid%2FContextual%2FMongo%3Alast).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the old behaviour is back in Mongoid 6? - I'm using 6.1.0 and I'm experiencing the following:

```
t(prod)> Benchmark.measure { Event.where(:created_at => 7.days.ago..1.day.ago).first }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00000003cb00b8 @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @label="", @real=4.109985898248851, @stime=0.0, @total=0.0, @utime=0.0>
t(prod)> Benchmark.measure { Event.where(:created_at => 7.days.ago..1.day.ago).limit(1).entries.first }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x000000037377f8 @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @label="", @real=2.6328365616500378, @stime=0.0, @total=0.0, @utime=0.0>
```

So using .first instead of .limit(1).entries.first is about twice as slow. One workaround is to do: .first(id_sort: :none)

hope that helps :)