# How to save 2 documents in mongodb collection instead of 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

On rails console, I am trying to save 2 categories in my book class. However my output returns 1 category.

My code:

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :publisher, type: String
  field :published_on, type: Date
  field :votes, type: Array
  belongs_to :author
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  embeds_many :reviews
end


class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end


class Author
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_many :books
end
```

Output on terminal

```
irb(main):001:0> b = Book.new(title: "Oliver Twist", publisher: "Dover Publications", published_on: Date.parse("2002-12-30") )

=> #<Book _id: 5833129213197da7660c0adb, title: "Oliver Twist", publisher:       "Dover Publications", published_on: 2002-12-30 00:00:00 UTC, votes: nil,   author_id: nil, category_ids: nil>
irb(main):002:0> Author.create(name: "Charles Dickens")
=> #<Author _id: 5833129a13197da7660c0adc, name: "Charles Dickens">

irb(main):003:0> Category.create(name: "Fiction")
=> #<Category _id: 583312a113197da7660c0add, name: "Fiction", book_ids: nil>

irb(main):004:0> Category.create(name: "Drama")
=> #<Category _id: 583312a813197da7660c0ade, name: "Drama", book_ids: nil>

irb(main):006:0* 
irb(main):007:0* b.author = Author.where(name: "Charles Dickens").first
=> #<Author _id: 5832d97713197da0893c05b9, name: "Charles Dickens">

irb(main):008:0> b.categories << Category.first
=> [#<Category _id: 58330d7d13197da0893c05ba, name: "Fiction", book_ids:           [BSON::ObjectId('5832d96913197da0893c05b8'),    BSON::ObjectId('5833129213197da7660c0adb')]>]

irb(main):009:0> b.categories << Category.last
=> [#<Category _id: 58330d7d13197da0893c05ba, name: "Fiction", book_ids:  [BSON::ObjectId('5832d96913197da0893c05b8'), BSON::ObjectId('5833129213197da7660c0adb')]>]

irb(main):010:0> 
irb(main):011:0* 

irb(main):012:0* b
=> #<Book _id: 5833129213197da7660c0adb, title: "Oliver Twist", publisher:     "Dover Publications", published_on: 2002-12-30 00:00:00 UTC, votes: nil,    author_id: BSON::ObjectId('5832d97713197da0893c05b9'), category_ids:   [BSON::ObjectId('58330d7d13197da0893c05ba')]>

irb(main):013:0> b.save
=> true

irb(main):014:0> Category.first
=> #<Category _id: 58330d7d13197da0893c05ba, name: "Fiction", book_ids:    [BSON::ObjectId('5832d96913197da0893c05b8')]>

irb(main):015:0> Category.last
=> #<Category _id: 58330d7d13197da0893c05ba, name: "Fiction", book_ids:    [BSON::ObjectId('5832d96913197da0893c05b8')]>
irb(main):016:0>
```

both categories show name as 'fiction' not 'drama'
futhermore, under testing -

```
> db.books.findOne()
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5833129213197da7660c0adb"),
  "title" : "Oliver Twist",
  "publisher" : "Dover Publications",
  "published_on" : ISODate("2002-12-30T00:00:00Z"),
  "author_id" : ObjectId("5832d97713197da0893c05b9"),
  "category_ids" : [
    ObjectId("58330d7d13197da0893c05ba")
 ]
}
> 
> 
> db.categories.findOne()
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58330d7d13197da0893c05ba"),
  "name" : "Fiction",
  "book_ids" : [
    ObjectId("5832d96913197da0893c05b8")
  ]
}
```

How do I ensure that 2 categorie_ids appear on db.books.findOne() ?

Will much appreciate your advice..

Comment: I found an alternative way of adding the second category to books collection. Use b.categories.create(name: "drama") on rails console.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [document](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/5.0.1/Mongoid%2FContextual%2FMongo%3Afirst), you have to explicity provide the sort order in order to make the first and last method work properly.

Something like this,

```
b.categories << Category order_by(:created_at => 'asc').first
b.categories << Category order_by(:created_at => 'asc').last
```

Source: [The bug of mongoid returning first document when invoking last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039847/the-bug-of-mongoid-returning-first-document-when-invoking-last)

Comment: Hi Jayaprakash, Thanks for the prompt reply and input, I tried adding mentioned commands but to no avail. There was an error message. However, I also found an alternative answer to this which appears to work.